# Javascript not updating img

Tags: javascript, image, cesiumjs

I'm using Cesium and trying to have a button that changes the image whenever pressed.  Cesium runs on javascript but whenever the variable changes that contains the name of the image file, the image does not change.

```
    var iName = "HeatMap"; var count=1;
name=iName.concat(count.toString());
var viewer = new Cesium.CesiumWidget('cesiumContainer');
var layers = viewer.scene.imageryLayers;

//Cesium Active Window
layers.addImageryProvider(new Cesium.SingleTileImageryProvider({
    url : 'images/'.concat(name.concat('.png')),
    rectangle : Cesium.Rectangle.fromDegrees(-180.0, -90.0, 180.0, 90.0),
    opacity:.3
}));

function buttonPressCount()
{
    name='HeatMap';
    count=count+1;
    name = name.concat(count.toString());
    document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = name;
}
```

the document.getElementById is just for debugging purposes so I know that the name actually changed.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me you should call something like

```
layers.addImageryProvider(new Cesium.SingleTileImageryProvider({
   url : 'images/'.concat(name.concat('.png')),
   rectangle : Cesium.Rectangle.fromDegrees(-180.0, -90.0, 180.0, 90.0),
   opacity:.3}));
```

in function buttonPressCount.

Comment: Yes, but he should also remove the existing imageryProvider (or all imageryProviders) so he doesn't end up with a whole stack of them.

Comment: Thanks worked, perfectly.  I just put the block of code in a function called reloadCesium() and call it when needed. Thanks a bunch.